# auditing filelds in spring data

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm beginner in java programming. And I try to write simple stand alone application with spring data. To basic example which is here http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/  I want to add, auditing mechanism which will store previous values for objects. I want in customer entity, on @PreUpdate store old values in another table, but I do not know how.

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Customer implements Serializable {
...
@Transient
private transient Customer savedState;

@PreUpdate
public void onPreUpdate() {

  if (!savedState.firstName.equals(this.firstName)) {

            log.info(String.format("first name was modified, new value =%s, old value=%s",this.firstName, savedState.firstName ));
        }
   }

@PostLoad
private void saveState(){
   this.savedState = (Customer) SerializationUtils.clone(this); // from apache commons-lang
    }
```

Comment: If you use Hibernate as your JPA engine, use [Envers](http://hibernate.org/orm/envers/).

Comment: Skimming through my JPA certification notes i stumbled upon a line that you cannot call the EntityManager from within a callback method, so if you want to persist data in a different table that may not be possible solely by specification. If you want to just log the state of the entity before update then you can use a method which accepts the entity class and extract the state from that: '@PreUpdate public void onPreUpdate(Customer customer)'. Hope that helps.